# What is the group shaming event stardew valley

Tags: stardew-valley

What is a group shaming event? I know it happens if your at ten hearts with all dating canidates. I can’t see it myself because I already married someone (I don’t think it matters who but if you interested I married Haley) What happens in a group shaming event

Answer (score 5):

These events can trigger when you are unmarried, have 10 hearts with all 6 bachelors or all 6 bachelorettes, and have seen all their 10-heart cutscenes. An event occurs when the farmer enters Haley/Emily's House (bachelorettes) or the Stardrop Saloon (bachelors).

In the event, your girlfriends/boyfriends announce that they know what you're doing and are breaking up with you. The actual result is that they get mad and won't accept gifts for a week.

Holding a Rabbits Paw changes the event to a better event where they don't find out or break up with you.

If you want to see the events yourself:

- [Bachelors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OleavUMpVzI)
- [Bachelorettes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13bBdwrKBDU)